# How to track variable's values in Qt Creator debugger?

Tags: qt, debugging

As in any debugger I set a breakpoint at the line I want to debug, then I start debugging but there is no panel on the right side of the screen which displays the current values of my variables. How can I turn it on?

Comment: What are you trying to debug?

Comment: I didn't suspect it matters, just an ordinary application with Qt GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Start a debugging session and visit menu `Window > Views > ...`
There you can check/uncheck many choices including `Reset to Default Layout`

Comment: Thank you very much, I was looking for that for ages.